# ForbiddenAttributesError for polymorphic model in Rails 4

Tags: parameters, ruby-on-rails-4, cancan, mass-assignment, polymorphism

Rails 4 ships with strong_parameters, which is a great addition - but I've run into a problem with it. I have a polymorphic model `Comment` and I cannot for the life of me get the controller to accept the parameters it needs. Here is my code (shortened for clarity):

Routes:

```rb
resources :articles do
  resources :comments
end
```

Models:

```rb
class Article < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :comments, :as => :commentable
end

class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :commentable, :polymorphic => true
end
```

Controller:

```rb
class CommentsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :get_commentable

  def create
    @comment = @commentable.comments.new(comment_params)
    if @comment.save
      redirect_to @commentable, :notice => "Thank you!"
    else
      render :new
    end
  end

private

  def get_commentable
    resource, id = request.path.split("/")[1,2]
    @commentable = resource.singularize.classify.constantize.find(id)
    redirect_to :home unless defined?(@commentable)
  end

  def comment_params
    params.require(:comment).permit(:title, :message)
  end
end
```

Posted params (from form on articles#show):

```rb
{"authenticity_token"=>"v70nN8aFpofNw9vbVjhpsm9SwLOwKlOpNOEOTozUwCk=",
"comment"=>{"title"=>"Test","message"=>"Testing"},
"article_id"=>"1"}
```

Looks to me like it should work, yet whatever I try I get `ActiveModel::ForbiddenAttributesError in CommentsController#create` - even when I try

```rb
  def comment_params
    params.permit! 
  end
```

in the controller. I have no such problems with my other (non-polymorphic) models, which is why I suspect it has something to do with the polymorphism. Any ideas?

Comment: Actually, it seems this is an error caused by CanCan which I'm using to do role based authorization - disabling it allows the comments to be created. Hmmm.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the lack of answers seemed to indicate I was barking up the wrong tree here. The issue lies not with strong_parameters but with the CanCan gem that I use for doing role and action based authorization. Apparently it's got to do with how CanCan assigns params to objects (CanCan takes over the default ActionController methods) - see the details in [this bug report](https://github.com/ryanb/cancan/issues/571), specifically [the reply from "rewritten"](https://github.com/ryanb/cancan/issues/571#issuecomment-10753675). In short, putting this in my application controller solves the problem:

```
before_filter do
  resource = controller_name.singularize.to_sym
  method = "#{resource}_params"
  params[resource] &&= send(method) if respond_to?(method, true)
end
```

**Update:**

As pointed out by @scaryguy, if the method above is called from a controller that does not have an associated model it will fall over. The solution is simply to name the method and call it as a before_filter, while explicitly excluding it in those controllers which have no models (and hence would not benefit from CanCan's automatic ability assignment anyway). I reckon something like this:

```
before_filter :can_can_can

def can_can_can
  resource = controller_name.singularize.to_sym
  method = "#{resource}_params"
  params[resource] &&= send(method) if respond_to?(method, true)
end
```

And then in the model-less controller:

```
skip_before_filter :can_can_can
```

Comment: This was exactly the same problem I had and this solution worked perfectly.  I bet many more people have this problem as time passes.

Comment: Thanks @Ecnalyr, happy to hear it was of help to someone!

Comment: Yes it works BUT only when controller and model exist and both are properly named. This breaks things when you want to use a controller without a model.